# zoom a div tag in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, webview

I have a webpage [click here to see](http://eprodixgroup.co.uk/htmlpage3.html) and it contains a div tag with the dimension 350 X 207. This is fixed size.

In my iphone screen I need to enlarge/zoom and display the div(in landscape). I tried the below two lines one at a time in my html file. 
 //This line zooms the page but unable to customise the size.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing this programmatically I'd try checking off the "Scales Pages to Fit" property in Interface Builder in the UIWebView Attributes inspector.

As mentioned [here](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/14635-uiwebview-zoom.html), you can also set the zoom scale:

```
 for (UIScrollView *scroll in [webView subviews]) {
    // Set the zoom level.
    [scroll setZoomScale:2.5f animated:YES];
 }
```